# How to create composite primary key in cassandra using CLI?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

i try to make composite primary key using cassandr-CLI but i'm unable to do that, i am able to do that using Cqlsh.

can you help me out?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be addressed in other questions:

- [Create two composite columns with cassandra-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243825/create-two-composite-columns-with-cassandra-cli)
- [create Composite-keyed Table with cassandra-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800983/create-composite-keyed-table-with-cassandra-cli)

The constructor `CompositeType(keyelem1_type, keyelem2_type, keyelem3_type)` should be used in cassandra-cli. Example (from this website providing good overview on composite keys in CQL and cassandra-cli - http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.com/2012/10/cassandra-compositetype-overview-cql.html):

```
create column family TestComposite
  with comparator='CompositeType(UTF8Type, UTF8Type, LongType)'
  and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type',
  and defaut_validation_class = 'UTF8Type';
```

HTH.